# Flutter MultipartRequest : How to get the field value in python flask

Tags: python, api, flutter, flask

Flutter code

```
`Future<Response_Data> UploadImageAndData(File file, String filename, String username)async{           
        var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST',
        Uri.parse("http://x.x.x.x:port/user/app/check_form/"),);
        Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"};
        request.files.add(http.MultipartFile('pro_image',file.readAsBytes().asStream(),
        file.lengthSync(),filename: filename,),);
        request.fields['user_name'] = username; 
        request.headers.addAll(headers);
        var res = await request.send();                                                                                  
        final respStr = await res.stream.bytesToString();
        }`
```

How to get this **fields['user_name']** value in flask. Like i'm retrieving the image file with  `pro_image = request.files['pro_image']`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced enough in flutter,but for getting data from body(if you are sending data as json) you can use:

```
request.json['username']
```

or if you are sending data as a form-data you can just use:

```
request.form.get('username')
```